# Создать список списков по условию Python

Tags: python, списки

Есть списки с данными

- SAM = [1050, 2000, 2050, 2200]
- TELE = [[1050, 2050], [2050, 2200], [1050, 1050, 2000], [1050, 1050,
  2050], [1050, 1050, 1050, 1050]]

Не получается создать список списков (будет иметь вид таблицы). В списке TELE есть списки с комбинациями, в списке SAM значения. Как сделать список списков по количеству повторений значения из SAM в разных комбинациях

Результат: A = [[1, 0, 2, 2, 4], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
[image: список списков подобной матрицы]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fyh8.png)

Comment: Тимур Шадров. Нельзя ли показать Ваш код и объяснить что конкретно не получается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы воспользовался модулями Pandas и SciKit-Learn:

```
In [103]: import pandas as pd

In [104]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
```

сначала создадим список предложений из `TELE`:

```
In [105]: sents = [' '.join(map(str, lst)) for lst in TELE]

In [106]: print(sents)
['1050 2050', '2050 2200', '1050 1050 2000', '1050 1050 2050', '1050 1050 1050 1050']
```

словарь (vocabulary) для `CountVectorizer`:

```
In [107]: vocab = [str(w) for w in SAM]

In [108]: print(vocab)
['1050', '2000', '2050', '2200']
```

теперь можно воспользоваться [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html):

```
In [109]: vect = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r'(?u)\b\w+\b', vocabulary=vocab)

In [114]: r = pd.SparseDataFrame(vect.fit_transform(sents),
     ...:                        index=sents,
     ...:                        columns=vect.get_feature_names(),
     ...:                        default_fill_value=0).T
     ...:
```

результат в виде SparseDataFrame:

```
In [115]: r
Out[115]:
      1050 2050  2050 2200  1050 1050 2000  1050 1050 2050  1050 1050 1050 1050
1050          1          0               2               2                    4
2000          0          0               1               0                    0
2050          1          1               0               1                    0
2200          0          1               0               0                    0
```

результат в виде списка списков:

```
In [116]: r.values.tolist()
Out[116]: [[1, 0, 2, 2, 4], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: А если вывести просто в таком виде A = [[1, 0, 2, 2, 4], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]? Код будет упрощен?

Comment: @ТимурШадров, добавил в ответ...